# list from array within a list from array

Tags: javascript

Here is my JavaScript that displays a list of people and images beside them; and if the name is Jim than display also the list of products. But for some reasons the loop stops after Jim and his list:

```js
window.onload = function append() {

    var i = 0;
    while (i < 4) {
        console.log(i);
        if (people[i] === "Jim") {

            app("div", people[i]);

            var arr = document.createElement("ul");

            for (i = 0; i < Jim_list.length; i++) {
                var tt = opp("li", Jim_list[i]);
                arr.appendChild(tt);
            }

            document.body.appendChild(arr);

        } else {
            app("div", people[i]);
        }

        var create_i = document.createElement("img");
        create_i.src = "http://tattmight.com/albums/userpics/2013y/08/25/1/178/dsfaf.jpg";
        create_i.style.width = "10%";

        document.body.appendChild(create_i);
        document.write("<br/>");

        i++;
        console.log("end");
    }
}();
```

Comment: You use `i` as a counter for both loops.

Answer (score 1):

Your nested loop uses the same counter as the outer loop. Change it to a new variable:

```
for (var j = 0, jlen = Jim_list.length; j < jlen; j++) {
    var tt = opp("li", Jim_list[j]);
    arr.appendChild(tt);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I figure it out)))))